# Controlling camera settings

Tags: java, image-processing, fmj

I am attempting to adjust camera settings such as exposure and white balance with the FMJ library in Java.  I can create a player dynamically:

```
new net.sf.fmj.media.cdp.civil.CaptureDevicePlugger().addCaptureDevices();

final java.util.Vector vectorDevices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);
Player player = null;
CaptureDeviceInfo cdi = ((CaptureDeviceInfo) vectorDevices.get(2));  // For simplicity now

try {
    player = Manager.createPlayer(cdi.getLocator());
    player.start();
} catch (NoPlayerException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So then I need to get the `Control`s of the `Player` to change the camera settings:

```
Control[] ctrls = player.getControls();
```

However, this is only returning a `RateControl`, when I need a `FrameGrabbingControl` to grab individual frames and (I'm assuming) `FormatControl` to change the camera settings ([source](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t494419-jmf-webcam-settings-resolution-gain-brightness-contrast.html)).

If these are not returned by `getControls()`, am I doomed?  I get the same results for these cameras: Microsoft Lifecam Studio and the built-in Lenovo EasyCam

Comment: Same thing with a Logitech C300

Comment: No luck, going through Directshow and JNI